# Organização de portfolio por categorias

Tags: php, jquery, html5, pdo

Analisando o **[MODELO](http://tecint.com.br/modelo-categorias)**, gostaria de alguma sugestão simples para classificar estes blocos por categorias dinâmicamente com os mesmos efeitos já existentes. 
Possuo uma uma tabela que salva o id do "produto" e os respectivos ids das categorias relacionadas a este produto.

> **categorias_produtos**
>   catp_id int(11) Não
>   catp_pro_id int(11) Sim     NULL
>   catp_cat_id varchar(255)    Sim     NULL
>
> **DADOS da tabela:**  
>   [image: dados da tabela categorias_produtos]

### Protótipo PHP (necessita solução):

Lembrando que os ids das categorias são processados em um `array` e separados por vírgula no banco de dados utilizando a função `explode`.

```
            <div class="section-content portfolio-section grid">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="filter">
                    <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*">Todas categorias</a></li>
                <?php $selCategoria = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY cat_nome ASC");
                $selCategoria->execute();

                if($selCategoria->rowCount() > 0):
                while($rowCategoria = $selCategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)): ?>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo $rowCategoria->cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $rowCategoria->cat_nome; ?></a></li>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                </ul>

                <div class="portfolio-box masonry two-col">

                <?php $selProdutos = $conn->prepare("SELECT p.pro_id, p.pro_nome, p.pro_status, p.pro_valor, p.pro_destaque, p.pro_brevedescricao, fp.posicao, fp.arquivo, cp.catp_cat_id 
                                                    FROM produtos p 
                                                    LEFT JOIN fotos_produtos fp ON p.pro_id = fp.id_produto AND fp.posicao = ?  
                                                    RIGHT JOIN produtos ON p.pro_status = ?
                                                    LEFT JOIN categorias_produtos cp ON cp.catp_pro_id = p.pro_id 
                                                    GROUP BY p.pro_id 
                                                    ORDER BY rand() "); 
                $selProdutos->execute(array(0,1));
                while($rowProduto = $selProdutos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)): ?>
                    <div class="project-post <?php echo $rowProduto->catp_cat_id; ?>">
                        <div class="project-gal">
                            <img alt="" src="<?php echo URL; ?>administracao/imagens/produtos/tamanho1_<?php echo $rowProduto->arquivo; ?>">                                
                        </div>
                        <h2><?php echo $rowProduto->pro_nome; ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $rowProduto->pro_brevedescricao; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

### Estrutura HTML:

Ignore a origem das classes nesta estrutura. Pode-se observar que o nome da categoria é processado dentro da tag `data-filter`, no PHP montei algo semelhante com o ID das categorias separado por vírgula no `data-filter`.

```
        <div class="section-content portfolio-section grid">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="filter">
                    <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*">Todas categorias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".design">Categoria 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".animation">Categoria 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".photography">Categoria 3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="portfolio-box masonry two-col">
                    <div class="project-post design">
                        <div class="project-gal">
                            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/460x300">                              
                        </div>
                        <h2>Cras ornare tristique</h2>
                        <p>Vivamus vestibulum nulla nec ante.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-post animation photography">
                        <div class="project-gal">
                            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/460x300">                          
                        </div>
                        <h2>Cras ornare tristique</h2>
                        <p>Vivamus vestibulum nulla nec ante.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-post design">
                        <div class="project-gal">
                            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/460x300">                              
                        </div>
                        <h2>Cras ornare tristique</h2>
                        <p>Vivamus vestibulum nulla nec ante.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-post photography">
                        <div class="project-gal">
                            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/460x300">                          
                        </div>
                        <h2>Cras ornare tristique</h2>
                        <p>Vivamus vestibulum nulla nec ante.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-post design">
                        <div class="project-gal">
                            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/460x300">                          
                        </div>
                        <h2>Cras ornare tristique</h2>
                        <p>Vivamus vestibulum nulla nec ante.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="project-post animation">
                        <div class="project-gal">
                            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/460x300">                              
                        </div>
                        <h2>Cras ornare tristique</h2>
                        <p>Vivamus vestibulum nulla nec ante.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: com números e virgulas na classe não vai funcionar, crie uma palavra chave para cada categoria e separe-as com espaço e não virgula... a proposito essa sua estrutura de tabelas esta meio estranha, para concatenar os IDs de categorias assim, não precisaria ser em uma tabela separada, poderia ser um campo na mesma tabela produtos...

Comment: A princípio está assim porque sua utilização era diferenciada anteriormente. No caso algum tempo atrás desenvolvi algo parecido porém, sem êxito, onde utilizei uma função `in_array`, para verificar se há determinado número no `data-filter`. Pensei em algo assim, desenvolvi a lógica, porém sem sucesso na prática. A princípio acho que deve existir alguma maneira utilizando os ids, caso contrário irei redesenvolver esta parte.

Answer (score 1):

Se você usar uma estrutura de tabelas como no modelo abaixo, acho que você consegue consultar facilmente todas as categorias do produto e obter a classe de cada uma...

**Tabela categorias:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorias` (
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_categoria` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `classe_categoria` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image: tabela categorias]

**Tabela produtos:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produtos` (
  `id_produto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_produto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `descricao_produto` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image: tabela produtos]

**Tabela produtos para categorias:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produtos_para_categorias` (
  `id_produto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`,`id_categoria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image: tabela produtos_para_categorias]

**Um exemplo de consulta para o produto ID 1:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `produtos_para_categorias` 
LEFT JOIN `categorias` 
USING ( id_categoria ) 
WHERE id_produto =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image: select]